# Javascript equivalent of PHP's sscanf function?

Tags: php, javascript, string, scanf

Pretty basic question. I have a string, it will always be in the format of "(45.234235235,55.345345345)" with variable numbers of decimal places. I want to extract both of these numbers. In PHP I would sscanf, but I want to do this in Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing like `sscanf`, but you can use [**`.replace()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [**`.split()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var data = str.replace(/[()\s]+/g, '').split(',');
```

Comment: Really quickly, will this simply return an array with two values?

Comment: Do the parenthesis in the regex need to be escaped?

Comment: @WiseOldDuck: Inside a character group (`[...]`), only `-` and `]` have to be escaped (so: no)

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard of the [php.js](http://phpjs.org/pages/home) project?

http://phpjs.org/functions/sscanf:886

This is to directly answer your question only. The JavaScript-native way to tackle your problem would be to use regular expressions. See [Felix Kling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860514/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-sscanf-function/5860534#5860534) for the proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer the question, the Javascript equivalent of PHP's (or C's) sscanf function are regexp submatches. For example, if in C you have:

```
const char *input = "SN/94321 2023/May/06 123.45";
sscanf(input, "SN/%u %4u/%3s/%2u %f", &id, &year, &mon, &day, &cost);
```

In Javascript you have:

```
const parser = /SN\/(\d+) (\d+)\/(\w+)\/(\d+) (\d+(\.\d+)?)/;
const input = "SN/94321 2023/May/06 123.45";
var tokens = input.match(parser);
var id = Number(tokens[1]), year = Number(tokens[2]), mon = tokens[3], day = Number(tokens[4]), cost = Number(tokens[5]);
```

Generally, it's far more efficient to perform parsing in a single step, natively, with a pre-compiled regexp, than doing it by script.

By the way, the Javascript-native way to address external representation (input parsing) is `JSON.parse();`